# Cute file browser in WP plugin - $.get don't retrieve php file

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to implement the "cute file browser" from tutorialzine into a Wordpress plugin, via shortcode.
I managed to push the script/css via wp_enqueue_scripts, but seems like the

```
$.get('scan.php' , function (data)[..]
```

doesn't work.

This is the call action in the main.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/css/styles.css' );
    wp_register_script( 'script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/script.js' , array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false);
}
```

This is how I created the script.js using the non-conflict mode, but there's some issue with the $.get

```
(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){ 

    var filemanager = $('.filemanager'),
        breadcrumbs = $('.breadcrumbs'),
        fileList = filemanager.find('.data');


    // Start by fetching the file data from scan.php with an AJAX request

$.get('scan.php' , function (data){
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

This is the output into scan.php

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    "name" => "files",
    "type" => "folder",
    "path" => $dir,
    "items" => $response
));
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Does it not run, is there an error message? Please be more specific

Comment: Seems like it doesn't execute the $.get. In fact I made a lil try:
<code>
(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){ 

 var filemanager = $('.filemanager'),
  breadcrumbs = $('.breadcrumbs'),
  fileList = filemanager.find('.data');
  alert('1st try');

 // Start by fetching the file data from scan.php with an AJAX request

$.get('scan.php' , function (data){
 alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
alert('2rd try);</code>

Just the first and the third alert were executed

Comment: First, have a look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ and see how they deal with errors using the `.fail` callback. Second, open the developer console. Do you see any errors there? If not, check out the Network tab in Chrome or an equivalent and rerun the page. The request should show up there. If you find it and the status code is good, check the response value

Comment: I found two error, the 1st:
if I use '$.get('scan.php' [...] ' the path would be **http://www.website.it/lace/scan.php**, instead of the correct **http://www.website.it/wp-content/plugins/lace/scan.php**
(lace is the page name as well the plugin name).
How could I create a dynamic reference? At the moment I just use the direct reference and found the 2nd error:

- The ajax call get an error if in scan.php i try to push the JSON array, so seems like there's something wrong into that...

The weird thing is that in the original way everything works well, but not if I use it in WP plugin.

Comment: In particularly there's an issue into the header:
 ' header('Content-type: application/json'); '
Commenting it, I got the response from scan.php, even if it's not correct...

Comment: But `scan.php` is not a JSON file, so why do you read it as JSON? Or is it a JSON file when you receive it? In that case, just remove the header, read it in as string and parse it using `JSON.parse(<string>)`. For the first thing, you can use the `location` object in your JavaScript console to construct an absolute URL dynamically - so you can prepend `website.it` to `/wp-content/plugins/lace/scan.php` where `website.it` is decided on dynamically

Comment: Is a php file that give me a JSON response, this is why I need to leave the header, otherwise I will read it like a normal text/html; charset=UTF-8. 
Seems like the issue anyway is in the rendering: if I don't have file in the folder searched the "no files here" message is showed, if there is something, I can see the correct response by the scan.php but is not rendered.
It's really weird because I didn't change the script, and plain without Wordpress works well....

Comment: Ok, I'm really close to the end :) I retrieve correctly all the file, but the object are not rendered because of an attribute 'display:none" on the list folder that I don't know where it comes out.

I solved (even if it's not the best way) using fileList.show() at the end of the render, even if I don't know still what modify its attribute before.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with that, because it will probably have something to do with your WordPress theme. Maybe you're using the same classname as is used by the theme? Is the attribute a `style` tag? Or is it applied by a `class`?

Comment: I thought about the them as well, but the attribute is a style tag

Comment: Yes, but then it must be added in the JavaScript somewhere. Have a look where this happens, look for the strings `display` and `none` in the source code of the website. If you cannot find it, add a new style rule yourself with the `!important` flag

Comment: Exactly, this is how I solved :) Thank you so much Ruben!
Anyway I still got issue with this plugin :( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753538/cute-file-browser-in-wp-plugin-wp-get-current-user-error)