# Cute file browser in WP plugin - wp_get_current_user error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm still trying to use Cute File Browser into a WP Plugin: after solved all the issue I'm banging my head with the wp_get_current_user.

The plugin is made from a main.php:

```
add_shortcode("lace", "lace_shortcode");
function lace_shortcode(){

        $html_code= '
        <div class="filemanager">

          <div class="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Ricerca un file.." />
          </div>

          <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>

          <ul class="data"></ul>

          <div class="nothingfound">
            <div class="nofiles"></div>
            <span>Nessun file trovato.</span>
          </div>

        </div>';
        wp_enqueue_script('script');
      return $html_code;
}
```

that call script.js:

```
(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){ 

    var filemanager = $('.filemanager'),
        breadcrumbs = $('.breadcrumbs'),
        fileList = filemanager.find('.data');

    const SCANPHP_DIR = ("http://localhost/www.website.it/wp-content/plugins/lace/scan.php");

    // Start by fetching the file data from scan.php with an AJAX request

    $.get(SCANPHP_DIR, function(data) {
```

who use the info from the scan.php:

```
function scan($dir){

    $files = array();
    /$user = 'administrator';

    // Is there actually such a folder/file?

    if(file_exists($dir)){

        foreach(scandir($dir) as $f) {

            //if admin, see al folders/files, otherwise just user folders/files
            if ($user!='administrator'){
                if($f != $user){
                    continue;
                }
            } [...]
```

I need to retrieve the current WP user in order to execute correctly the plugin, but here comes the issue.
I can use correctly $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); into the shortcode, but I don't know how to do that in the scan.php: if I try to use the same way, I couldn't execute it, maybe because the scan.php is loaded before the init of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access wordpress functions inside scan.php as this file is working as a standalone file as it is called through ajax.

If you want to use wordpress functions then you need to call ajax the right way.

Check this link:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins